# Correlation of X and Y, when E[X] = 0

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, covariance, correlation

X and Y are random variables and it is known that E(X) is zero. Then how can I prove that corr(X,Y)is zero?

Here is what I tried:
The covariance between two random variables X and Y is defined as: Cov(X,Y)=E[(X−E[X])(Y−E[Y])] If E[X]=0

Then the covariance simplifies to: Cov(X,Y)=E[X(Y−E[Y])]=E[XY]−E[X]E[Y]=E[XY]−0⋅E[Y]=E[XY]

So, if E[X]=0, then E[XY]=E[X]⋅E[Y]=0⋅E[Y]=0

So the covariance is zero. Therefore, the correlation of X and Y is also zero.
Does this hold for any two random variables (where one has zero expectation) or are there conditions which I have to assume. Or does the proof has some mistake?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What's the definition of $\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)$? What information does $\mathbb E(X) = 0$ give you?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @kipf , Anne
Here is what I tried:

The covariance between two random variables X and Y is defined as: 
Cov(X,Y)=E[(X−E[X])(Y−E[Y])] If E[X]=0, 

then the covariance simplifies to: 

Cov(X,Y)=E[X(Y−E[Y])]=E[XY]−E[X]E[Y]=E[XY]−0⋅E[Y]=E[XY]

So, if E[X]=0, then E[XY]=E[X]⋅E[Y]=0⋅E[Y]=0

So the covariance is zero. Therefore, the correlation of X and Y is also zero. 

Does this hold for any two random variables (where one has zero expectation) or are there conditions which I have to assume. Or does the proof has some mistake?

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{E}XY\ne\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y$$

In general, even when$\mathbb{E}X=0$
E.g.
$$X=Y\sim N(0,1)$$
Then
$$\mathbb{E}XY=\mathbb{E}X^2=1$$
And
$$\mathbb{E}X=0$$

Comment: It might be worth saying that this is a counterexample, showing $\mathbb E[X]=0$ does not generally imply $\mathbb E[XY]=0$ or that the covariance or correlation is $0$